# SQL server agent, OLAP cube

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, olap-cube

I wanted to get your input about what to check for when processing an OLAP cube as a job in SQL Server Agent and more how to display it in Excel?

1. Create the Facttable(s) and Dimension tables
2. Create OLAP cube
3. Process and deploy OLAP cube (check if it works)
4. Setup a job in SQL Server Agent (creating the Fact, Dim and Processing/Deploy OLAP cube)
5. Go to EXCEL, connect from other sources: Analysis Services.
6. Select to appropriate server
7. Select Database that contains the data you want
8. Connect to a specif cube or table

I already have followed these steps with 2 prior cubes and they display in step 8.

But I am having a problem with my 3rd cube that is not displaying.

What do you usually check for when something like this happens??

Thanks for any help,
Alfred

Comment: At which step is it not displaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found out what it was. Under the cube properties 'Visible' was set to False, changed it to true and deployed it again.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to analysis services and verify that the database exists and that it has been processed.

Comment: OK, did this but still not able to view the cube in the Data Connection Wizard (Excel).
Could it be something with rules, user setup?

Comment: Browse the cube from management studio to verify that its' not corrupt and its' state is processed. It seems strange that you repeated these steps for all 3 cubes but can only connect to 2 from Excel.

Comment: OK, found out what it was. Under the cube properties 'Visible' was set to False, changed it to true and deployed it again.